# Xslt mapping for multiple values to one

Tags: xslt-2.0, bpel

i have source XML as like below

```
<Input>    
<email-addresses>
    <type>work</type>
    <value>tst@work.com</value>
    </email-addresses>
    <email-addresses>
    <type>personal</type>
    <value>tst@personal.com</value>
    </email-addresses>
</Input>
```

Output should be like below

```
<output>
<emailwork>tst@work.com</emailwork>
<emailper>tst@personal.com</emailper>
</output>
```

I am using below xslt mapping in my code to get the above output

```
 <output>
<xsl:if test "Input/email-address/type='work'">
<emailwork>
<xsl:value of select= "Input/email-address/value">
</emailwork>

</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test "Input/email-address/type='personal'">
<emailper>
<xsl:value of select= "Input/email-address/value">
</emailper>

</xsl:if>
 </output>
```

but it always returns the first emailaddress which appears in the payload.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You need to **iterate** through your payload, so that xslt will go through all the records. Try adding ***for-each*** loop to your xslt.